# Joomla 3 EShop or j2Store

Tags: joomla-3.x, e-commerce

I'm needing to make a choice between a couple of joomla ecommerce systems. Having used and hated virtuemart a long time ago and again recently I'm looking for another solution and there's no shortage.

After a fair bit of research narrowed it down to https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/eshop/ & https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/j2store/ which both get very good reviews. One of them has a backend demo, so can't compare in that way, both have frontend demo.

I wondered from personal experiences what others have to say about these 2 systems - positive & negative?

Limitations, future extensibility/development, maintenance. Features like custom product field options.

I'm a designer/builder, not a developer to give some context.

Many thanks for any advice received and your time, it is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure as I did not use `eshop`, but as a designer, I believe, you should be comfortable with j2store.

Comment: Thankyou Alexandr. I will do an in-depth comparison of the two to see.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing an e-commerce solution depends on the requirements for each particular project. What shipping option(s), payment option(s) and tax option(s) etc. are required? Even minor features such as the layout of the printed receipt could be a deal breaker for a particular project.

Start with the list or requirements and find a solution that fits the project rather than trying to make the project fit a solution.

Once you have the list of requirements, it should be much easier to narrow down the list of potential solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Neil. I was really hoping to use one tool though that I could master for a wide variety of use cases and offer jobs based on that system and it's available extensible features. It's just so difficult without experience with either to be able to make any kind of decision. One thing, for example, I'd like to do is migrate some clients sites from woocommerce to the new choice.

Comment: Hi Phil, your question is probably beyond the scope of Joomla Stack Exchange unless you have a detailed list of specific requirements. What works for me (e.g. I usually need an Australia Post shipping option) isn't necessarily relevant for you. Reading the reviews on the JED at http://extensions.joomla.org might help?

Comment: Thanks, it's made me realise the necessity to dig a lot deeper. Although would still be interested to hear any positive and negatives from experienced users.

Comment: Hi Phil, I think the difference between the two choices you listed is what can be done with them. EShop is a good component, but like most of the other e-commerce solutions, it can not be modified very much from out of the box. If your project suits its framework, then it is a solid little number.
If you need a lot of flexibility, then I would suggest J2Store, where at the minimum you will need to create a sub-template for your layout, there are also a myriad of plugins available for it to add to the capability. Think of J2Store as our answer to WooCommerce (shoot me now).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your first choice but I have been using J2store on a couple sites I manage since it was first available, I think that was around 2012-2013.  It has come a long, long way and I'm certain they have a payment and shipping plugin to match the needs of virtually every user.  If not I'm also quite certain they would build what you need on request.  Often they will not charge you for custom created plugins/apps IF it is something that would appeal to many other users instead they will release it as an extension after getting it working for you.

The entire system is very easy to use, built upon the native Joomla system so no conflicts as it all works seamlessly.  The interface is intuitive, I suggest installing the free version to check it out but upgrade to the Pro version if you keep it.

I have been using Joomla to create sites since the late 1990's and tried a great deal of carts and other extensions.  Bar none, J2store has the best support and response you will find anywhere.  They continually blow me away with their willingness to help whether you are new to Joomla or not.

Keep in mind I am basing my experience on using the yearly subscription to Pro version which comes with ticket support.  I don't believe the free version comes with support although they have a forum for free users.  I have lurked there and their responses there are another reason I don't hesitate to recommend them, they rarely ignore free users like many other cart developers do and they are always knowledgeable, polite and respectful in their responses regardless of how ignorant the questions or outrageous the requests (for something free).

The cost for the Pro version is very reasonable and worth every single penny, year after year.  Seriously, nobody compares to their support.  These people deserve recognition for their quality support!

Comment: Late 1990's for Joomla, what do you know that I don't Lynne :)